# Memory of declared variable vs. when it is defined in function call

Tags: python, pandas, memory

So I have a general question, but since I'm writing in Python it is the tag.

Assume I have `df` which is a pandas dataframe -  I would normally do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data = cosine_similarity(df.T))
```

instead of

```
df=df.T
df = pd.DataFrame(data = cosine_similarity(df))
```

but then I thought: if *memory* is the issue (and not speed) would the second way be superior to the first? I assume that `cosine_similarity` have to calculate `df.T` in order to use it, thus using twice the memory (having both `df` and `df.T` stored in memory), untill the calculation is done.

Am I right or how is this exactly done?

Comment: No. Nothing new is allocated; you are just shuffling explicit references around.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `df.T` is computed (however that happens). The only difference is that in your first code, the result is bound to the parameter for `cosine_similarity`, while in the second, it is bound to the name `df` currently in scope. In both cases, the result of `pd.DataFrame` is then bound to `df`.

The only difference in memory usage would be *when* the original value of `df` gets garbage collected (if it does at all), as your first code reassigns `df` later than your second code does.

Answer (score 0):

#### [From Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L1027-L1038)

```
X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)


X_normalized = normalize(X, copy=True)
if X is Y:
    Y_normalized = X_normalized
else:
    Y_normalized = normalize(Y, copy=True)


K = safe_sparse_dot(X_normalized, Y_normalized.T,
                    dense_output=dense_output)


return K
```

`check_pairwise_arrays` determines if you passed a `Y`.  In your case, you did not.  If not, it makes `Y` the same as `X`.  As in pointing to the same memory location.  `cosine_similarity` seems to be handling memory just fine.

---

However, you are not.  You're making a whole new dataframe `df.T` unnecessarily.  Do this instead.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(df.to_numpy().T))
```

This way, you are pointing to the Numpy array that underlies the dataframe.  This should not be creating a new object.  Then transposing that array should also point to the same values in memory.  Also, I'm not certain of this 100% but it is my best reasoning as of now.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go, and see with the memory!